# Changing the Beamer Theme "Feather"?

Tags: beamer, tikz-styles, beamerposter

I wanna adjust the [Beamer Theme "Feather"](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/beamer-presentation-template-feather-theme/jcbpcdxqbxbf#.VabmlXXtlBd) for my needs:

- Change the Front Page
- Deleting the gray horizontal bar (@barcolor)
- Set the @headercolor to red
- Transpose the feather logo in the ring
- Replace the Final Page

There are four sty-files:

- beamercolorthemeFeather [BCT]
- beamerinnerthemeFeather [BIT]
- beamerouterthemeFeather [BOT]
- beamerthemeFeather      [BTF]

They can be downloaded in Overleaf.

**Front Page**

Should look like this

[image: Sun Front Page]

I have the [sun image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/Giant_prominence_on_the_sun_erupted.jpg), so I tried to add the text with tikz (it doesn't work). Here is what I tried:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(1920,1080)
\put(0,0){\includegraphics{../../Downloads/sun.jpg}}
\put(200,1500){{\color{red} Th} {\color{white}ermodynamics}\\ \bigskip {\color{white} by Sine Nomine Scriptus}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

**Change the Bar and the Header Colour**

I don't know how to delete the bar beneath the header (just the vertical line, not the ring line).

Add `\ProvidesPackage{html}` under line 19 in the [BCT] and change the @headercolor in the [BCT] in line 42:

```
\definecolor{beamer@headercolor}{HTML}{B40404} % red
```

**Logo substitution**

I would like to change the feather logo with this logo:

[image: Logo]

It can easily be done in [BOT] in line 199. Just change

```
\node at (logopos) {\includegraphics[width=1.75\beamer@logoradius]{Feathergraphics/URLOGO}};
```

**Final Page**

It should look like this:
[image: Question]

Change [BIT] line 92 to:

```
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{Feathergraphics/URLASTPAGEIMAGE}
```

**Minimal Working Example**

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Feather}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}

% colored hyperlinks
\newcommand{\chref}[2]{
  \href{#1}{{\usebeamercolor[bg]{Feather}#2}}

%titlepage
\title[Thermodynamics]{Thermodynamics}
\author[Sine Nomine Scriptus]


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Content}{}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{License}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}{License}
Text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]
  \finalpage{Thank you for using Feather Beamer Theme!}
\end{frame}}

\end{document}
```

**TROUBLE**

Creating the Front Page like I wanted to and insert it into my file. Deleting the Horizontal Gray Bar (not the gray bar around the ring).

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: The template says `The theme contains 4 source files:
  \begin{itemize}
    \item {\tt beamercolorthemeFeather.sty}
    \item {\tt beamerouterthemeFeather.sty}
    \item {\tt beamerinnerthemeFeather.sty}
    \item {\tt beamerthemeFeather.sty}
  \end{itemize}`. Have you looked at the `.sty` files? By the way, it is using font commands which were deprecated 20+ years ago and ought not be used in LaTeX.

Comment: @cfr ty ... I couldn't find them, but now I have found them and had a look. Nearly all my problems are solved - "just" need help with Creating the Front Page like I wanted to and insert it into my file. Deleting the Horizontal Gray Bar (not the gray bar around the ring).

Comment: It would be better to edit your question to ask just what you need to know. Right now, there is a lot of irrelevant information in there which makes it difficult to tell what your current question actually is. Also, does this actually have anything to do with that theme any more?

Comment: I hope one day future generations will look at every coat of arms existed on earth and wonder what we were smoking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

Here's what you need to do.

1. First of all, for licensing issues (the files are licensed under the GNU General Public License v. 3 (GPLv3)), it's better not to change the original files. Make a copy of the files

   ```
   beamercolorthemeFeather.sty
   beamerinnerthemeFeather.sty
   beamerouterthemeFeather.sty
   beamerthemeFeather.sty
   ```

   and rename the copies as, for example,

   ```
   beamercolorthememodFeather.sty
   beamerinnerthememodFeather.sty
   beamerouterthememodFeather.sty
   beamerthememodFeather.sty
   ```

   Add a note to the renamed files indication that they are modified version of their originals. All changes will be made to those renamed files; in particular, the changes you already made for the logo and the final page should be made on those copies.
2. In `beamerthemeFeather.sty`, change

   ```
          \useinnertheme{Feather}
          \useoutertheme{Feather}
          \usecolortheme{Feather}
   ```

   to

   ```
          \useinnertheme{modFeather}
          \useoutertheme{modFeather}
          \usecolortheme{modFeather}
   ```
3. To suppress the bar below the title, go to line 180 of a `beamerouterthememodFeather.sty` and comment out the line

   ```
   \draw[draw=none,fill=Feather.fg] (ULL) rectangle (LLR); % line below the background rectangle %
   ```
4. To change the title page, redefine the `title page` template; this can be done locally (i.e., in your `.tex` file) using

   ```
   \definecolor{redtitle}{RGB}{240,0,0}
   \setbeamerfont{title}{family=\sffamily,size=\huge,series=\bfseries}  
   \setbeamerfont{author}{family=\sffamily,size=\small,series=\bfseries}  
   \setbeamercolor*{author}{fg=white,bg=white}

   \defbeamertemplate*{title page}{mytheme}{%
     \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
     \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
       at (current page.center)
       (titlepageimage)
       {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{sun}};
     \node[anchor=south west,align=center] 
       at ([shift={(0pt,1cm)}]titlepageimage.south west)
       {%
         {\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle}\\[4pt]
         {\usebeamerfont{author}\usebeamercolor[fg]{author}by~\insertauthor}
       };   
     \end{tikzpicture}%
   }
   ```

   or globally replacing the definition for `title page` in the file `beamerinnerthememodFeather.sty`; I'd suggest you to do it locally, since it's a dramatic redefinition and it would be a good idea to keep the original one.
5. In your document, use the `modFeather` theme:

   ```
   \documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
   \usetheme{modFeather}
   ```

The code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{modFeather}
\usepackage{helvet}

%% setting the title page deffinitions
\definecolor{redtitle}{RGB}{240,0,0}
\setbeamerfont{title}{family=\sffamily,size=\huge,series=\bfseries}  
\setbeamerfont{author}{family=\sffamily,size=\small,series=\bfseries}  
\setbeamercolor*{author}{fg=white,bg=white}

\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{mytheme}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
    at (current page.center)
    (titlepageimage)
    {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{sun}};
  \node[anchor=south west,align=center] 
    at ([shift={(0pt,1cm)}]titlepageimage.south west)
    {%
      {\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle}\\[4pt]
      {\usebeamerfont{author}\usebeamercolor[fg]{author}by~\insertauthor}
    };   
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
%-------------------------------------------------------

\title[Thermodynamics]{\textcolor{redtitle}{Th}\textcolor{white}{ermodynamics}}
\author{Sine Nomine Scriptus}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Content}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{License}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
\framesubtitle{License}
test text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### Remark

As can be seen in my example, your logo image has a white rectangular background, so it doesn't fit well in the circle for the logo. It would be better to use an image with background removed or circularly cropped.

Comment: @Dr.HenrietteB.Fröhlich You're welcome! I've updated my answer with a longer explanation and comments.